# Django sem visualização de models no admin de usuario comum mesmo tendo permissões e estando no mesmo grupo

Tags: python, apache, django, permissões

Boa tarde,
Então estou tentando dar permissões que já vem no django para um usuário comum que mesmo pertencendo ao grupo não consegue acessar os models que é concedido a ele. Alguém teve esse problema da não visualização de models no admin. versão do python 2.7 e django 1.10

já tenho as conf do settings como  'django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'

no models eu tenho apenas:

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Paciente"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pacientes"
```

e no admin tenho:

```
class PacienteAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome','data_nascimento')

admin.site.register(Paciente, PacienteAdmin)
```

apenas isso e mesmo assim sem visualização do mesmo.
obrigada desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um teste com seu codigo e funciona perfeitamente, o único erro que vejo no código que vc postou aqui é no fragmento (admin.py):

```
class PacienteAdmin(ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('nome','data_nascimento')
```

Troque a linha:

```
class PacienteAdmin(ModelAdmin):
```

Para:

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
```

---

**Se não funcionar, tente seguir os passos:**

1) (linha de comando)

```
$ django-admin startproject myproject .
```

2) (linha de comando)

```
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

3) (linha de comando)

```
$ ./manage.py createsuperuser
```

4) (linha de comando)

```
$ ./manage.py startapp myapp
```

Após esses passos, a árvore do seu projeto devera parecer com a figura abaixo:

[image: Árvore do projeto]

5) Edit o arquivo models.py no diretorio myapp para que fique assim:

```
from django.db import models

class Paciente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Paciente"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pacientes"
```

6) Edit o arquivo admin em myapp, para que fique assim:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Paciente

class PacienteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome','data_nascimento')

admin.site.register(Paciente, PacienteAdmin)
```

7) Edite o arquivo settings.py para adiconar myapp, então a seção INSTALLED_APPS, deverá ficar assim:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Após esses passos, execute o projeto com runserver, entre em admin, crie um grupo e um usuario, dê permissao para que o usuario possa incluir mas não possa deletar pacientes. Se eu não cometi nenhum erro ao postar aqui e voce seguiu todos os passos corretamente, o resultado será o esperado.

Obs.:
O exemplo expresso aqui foi testado (e aprovado :-)) em um ambiente Linux.

Comment: Muitoo obrigada, resolvido o problema, acabei criando um outro projeto e feito os passos para verificar onde estava o erro.